# Install Fedora over Ubuntu partition?

Tags: fedora

Is there any way for me to install Fedora over Ubuntu in a partition I made?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily by start installing fedora and when you go to partitioning section choose to replace Ubuntu by fedora